# Professor's answer to Python homework will not run: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'gender'

Tags: oop, python-3.6

I'm sure this has been asked before, but at I'm not at the level where I can understand how the other question answers mine just yet. Can someone explain the problem with this code? I cannot see it:

```
class Person:
    name = ''
    age = 0
    gender = ''

    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender


class Employee(Person):
    title = ''
    salary = 0

    def __init__(self, name, age, gender, title, salary):
        Person.__init__(name, age, gender)
        self.title = title
        self.salary = salary


George = Employee("George", 30, "Male", "Manager", 50000)
print("George's info is: Name is %s, Age is %d, Gender is %s, Title is %s, and Salary is %d" % (
George.name, George.age, George.gender, George.title, George.salary))
```

The error returned in PyCharm is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Sam/PycharmProjects/HW7/HW7-q2_Profs-Solution.py", line 22, in <module>
    George = Employee("George", 30, "Male", "Manager", 50000)
  File "/Users/DrewAndMon/PycharmProjects/HW7/HW7-q2_Profs-Solution.py", line 17, in __init__
    Person.__init__(name, age, gender)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'gender'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The call to `Person.__init__` should be `Person.__init__(self, ...)`. Or, better, use `super().__init__`.

Comment: Thanks, @kaya3. Could you link an example, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```py
        Person.__init__(name, age, gender)
```

to:

```py
        Person.__init__(self, name, age, gender)
```

Explanation: the `Person.__init__` method takes four parameters, the first one of which is the `self` parameter for the object being initialized. Normally, the `self` parameter is special in that it automatically takes the value of the object that the method is called on. However, since `Person` is a class, not an object, in this case the method is not being called on an object, so `self` parameter must be passed as an explicit argument.

It is more normal to write this instead as:

```py
        super().__init__(name, age, gender)
```

This looks a bit stranger, but it avoids unnecessarily writing the name of the parent class a second time, and it works correctly when a class has two superclasses.

Answer (score 0):

What needs to be changed is the call to the `Person.__init__(name, age, gender)` in class `Employee`, in definition it is `def __init__(self, name, age, gender):`
Your correct code is-

```
class Person:
    name = ''
    age = 0
    gender = ''

    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender


class Employee(Person):
    title = ''
    salary = 0

    def __init__(self, name, age, gender, title, salary):
        Person.__init__(self, name, age, gender)
        self.title = title
        self.salary = salary


George = Employee("George", 30, "Male", "Manager", 50000)
print("George's info is: Name is %s, Age is %d, Gender is %s, Title is %s, and Salary is %d" % (
George.name, George.age, George.gender, George.title, George.salary))
```

And this will give you your output as-

```
George's info is: Name is George, Age is 30, Gender is Male, Title is Manager, and Salary is 50000
```

Comment: I don't see a change to the original code...?? What is it exactly? Also, when I copy/paste this into PyCharm it gives the exact same error as before.